# Являются ли функции в VB.NET функциями высшего порядка?

Tags: функции, vb.net, функциональное-программирование

Являются ли функции в VB.NET функциями высшего порядка?

Comment: Короткий ответ - да, но использовать их в таком качестве можно только через делегаты

Comment: Функции высшего порядка это функции над функциями. Они принимают функции в качестве аргументов и/или возвращают функции. Так что правильный ответ - да, но далеко не все

Comment: @extrn Вопрос был задан не ради того, что бы задать вопрос, а что бы увидеть развернутый ответ.

Comment: Я не готов дать развернутый ответ, именно поэтому написал комментарий. Для примера можете рассмотреть методы расширения LINQ (если они доступны в VB) там сплошь функции высшего порядка.

Comment: Конечно доступны. Еще бы они не были доступны. Чего стоит только один факт того что в Visual Studio 2015 компилятор написали заново на VB.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Delegate Function Operation(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer

Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine(Evaluate(AddressOf Add, 55, 66))
    Console.WriteLine(Evaluate(AddressOf [Sub], 100, 36))
    Console.WriteLine(Evaluate(AddressOf Multiply, 5, 66))
    Console.WriteLine(Evaluate(AddressOf Div, 500, 55))

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

Function Evaluate(f As Operation, x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    Return f(x, y)
End Function

Function Add(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    Return x + y
End Function

Function [Sub](x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    Return x - y
End Function

Function Multiply(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    Return x * y
End Function

Function Div(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    Return x / y
End Function
```

Comment: Здесь нет ни одной функции высшего порядка

Comment: @extrn  Да возможно, тогда я с радостью увидел бы реальный пример...

Comment: Я не пишу на vb.net, но если бы у вас была функция вроде `Function Evaluate(f as Operation, x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer` которая бы принимала функцию, ее аргументы, и возвращала результат ее работы, это уже была бы функция высшего порядка, потому, что ее аргументом является функция.

Comment: @extrn Хорошо спасибо, попробую переписать код. Изучаю просто питон и примеряю возможности на vb.net.

Comment: В python типичными функциями высшего порядка являются `map`, `filter`, `sorted` (первые две скорее по смыслу, чем по содержанию) да и много разных других.

Comment: Вот теперь все в порядке :)

Comment: @extrn Да я это знаю. Переписал код, так уже чуть лучше.